# map with compression of key ranges with equal value

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, range, binary-search-tree, intervals

I'm on the lookout for a data structure which acts sort of like a `Map[Ordered, Any]` with low space requirements for intervals of identical-valued keys. It should support the following operations:

- `Upsert([lo, hi], value)`: insert all keys in the interval, all mapping to the given value; overwrite/remove any already existing keys in that range.
- `Delete([lo, hi])`: remove all keys in the given range from the map.
- `Query(x) -> Maybe[value]`: return the value associated with `x` if any, or some indication of its absence if that's the case.

Note that `Upsert([1, 10], A) ; Upsert([5, 13], B)` yields `{1-4: A, 5-13: B}`. My understanding of range/interval/segment trees is that they do something slightly different, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

It should preferably use O(1) storage per interval of equal-valued keys, and use O(log n) time (or better) per operation.  Amortized bounds are OK, but I would prefer per-operation bounds.

My own partial solution is to use an unbalanced binary search tree, which obviously won't get me to O(log n) time.  The reason it's non-obvious how to proceed is that insertions may delete large subtrees: suppose the tree contains keys 1..63 (all having different values), perfectly balanced, and you `upsert([1, 31], something_new)`: then the entire left subtree collapses down to a single node. How do you rebalance this in O(log n) time? I'm not sure...

Comment: In the worst case `O(1)` storage per interval with `O(logn)` time bound per iteration where `n` is the number of intervals is not possible. Consider the example where you have `n` disjoint intervals, and you do a single upsert that encompasses all `n` existing intervals. Is there a bound on the `hi` and `lo` values? Are all intervals going to be Integers?

Comment: Fair point. Assuming memory allocation and garbage collection is free, is it then possible? The tree reshaping can be done in O(log n) time: when you add [lo', hi'] and the root contains [lo, hi] with lo' < lo < hi < hi', you replace the root node with [lo', hi'] and remove [hi+1, hi'] from the right subtree and likewise in the left; this can be done in O(log n) time by removing some centre-most subtrees and perhaps adjusting one interval in the right(/left) subtree. (Removing a subtree is just setting a pointer to null which by perhaps bad assumption is O(1) time.)